# how to import external javascript to polymer project

Tags: javascript, gulp, polymer-1.0

I am completely new to polymer 1.x. i like to know how to import javascript file to my index.html . normal way of importing javascript not working for production version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to polymer below are the good resources to start understanding it

1. Developer guide: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview.html
2. Polymer element source codes. All the polymer elements are in github with the source code and demo code. http://github.com/polymerelements, https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse
3. Polymer starter kit: https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit. You can use this as base to build your application.

The answer for your question is in routing.html in the polymer-starter-kit. You just include it in script tag as you do in any html file.

```
<script src="../bower_components/page/page.js"></script>
```

Comment: my script is not global. i want it it particular div elemnt

Comment: Please provide complete details in your question, so that readers can understand your problem better and give you better answers.

Comment: <blink>
var countdown = $(".countdown").countdown360({
    radius: 60,
    seconds: 80,
    label: ['sec', 'secs'],
    fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    autostart: false,
    onComplete: function () {
      console.log('done');
    }
});

countdown.start();

$('#countdown').click(function() {
  countdown.extendTimer(2);
});
    </blink><br/>this is my .js file. i want use this with <br/><div class="countdown"></div>

Comment: how can i use routing.html to include .js

Comment: how to place a javascript inside body of index.html